# Run a class in workspace via Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on an Eclipse plug-in project and I want to to be able run a specific class via this plug-in.

For example I added a button to the eclipse interface and I want this button runs one specific Java class.

I am looking through the tutorials etc but I couldn't find how to make this.

Is there anyone that can give me some intuition?

Best

Comment: the link does not work.   edit: delete the last character

Answer (score 2):

You could use Runtime.exec(). But for a cleaner approach refer '[Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/)' library.